# VBNET - How to reset the table/contents of a matrix?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, matrix, visual-studio-2012

I think my question is very simply but I don't have any idea of how to do this...

My app draws some checkboxes and saves a values for each checkbox into a matrix:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim mcheck(0) As CheckBox
```

then with a control button I will load a thing in my form that requires that matrix empty again (0) without any table/value/instance like in my first declaration to add more values from scracth (0) (1) (2) etc...

What I need to do to reset the table/contents/values of that matrix?

PS: Really sorry for my english.

Thankyou for read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "matrix" in this case is an *Array*. VB knows the `ReDim` command to change the dimensions of an array. If you use `ReDim Preserve` the contents of the array are preserved, otherwise they get deleted/cleared. If you increase the size of the array and use `Preserve` old elements will not be deleted and the additional elements will be initialized with the default for the type of the array (0 for Integer, and so on). On decrease you will loose all elements that exceed the new dimension. If you Redim an array with the same size as it already has (and do NOT use `Preserve`) you are simply wiping out all elements.

But ...
I doubt that "Array" is the correct solution for your problem. Since you are doing something "dynamic", you'd probably better use a List(Of T) or something similar.